# Espresso: Getting a text value from a textview and storing in a String?

Tags: java, android-espresso

I wanted to assert a part of the 'text' i get from a textview and later store it in a string, but not sure how i am going to do this.

Following is the code snippet for reference :

```
private void validateFlightOverviewWidgetDate(int resId, String value, boolean outBound) throws Throwable {
    if (ProductFlavorFeatureConfiguration.getInstance().getDefaultPOS() == PointOfSaleId.UNITED_STATES) {
        onView(allOf(outBound ? isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.package_outbound_flight_widget))
                : isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.package_inbound_flight_widget)),
            withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE),
            withId(resId)))
            .check(matches(withText(containsString("Dec 22 "))));
```

I want to store the value of "Dec 22" in a string so that later i can use it for assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a custom `ViewAction` to help you to get text from `TextView`:

```
public class GetTextAction implements ViewAction {

    private CharSequence text;

    @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
    }

    @Override public String getDescription() {
        return "get text";
    }

    @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        text = textView.getText();
    }

    @Nullable
    public CharSequence getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Then you can get text by:

```
GetTextAction action = new GetTextAction();
onView(allOf(isDescendantOf(...), withId(...), withEffectiveVisibility(...)))
    .perform(action);

CharSequence text = action.getText();
```

Though I'd not recommend to use this way for test assertion, it seems unconventional and *awkward*. Also, you don't really need to have `isDescendantOf(...)` in your `allOf` combination because of `withId`, unless the id is not unique.